# RestKit - Nested object mapping failing if nesting value is a domain name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I need help on nested object mapping, I think I hit a bug.

When the nesting value is a domain (something.com), restkit substitutes it on the nested attributes and tries to find "something.com.name", "something.com.url", "something.com.email", assuming 2 nestings, the "something" and the "com", and therefore failing.

Here is the log of the mapping failing:

```
2014-01-07 14:14:25.408 MyAppName[923:7003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
    "myservice.co.tz" =     {
        countries =         (
            tz
        );
        flag = tz;
        name = Tanzania;
        url = "http://www.MyAppName.co.tz";
    };
} with mapping <RKObjectMapping:0x15591b20 objectClass=LMCountry propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x15591e10 <RK_NESTING_ATTRIBUTE> => host>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x15591f80 (host).name => name>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x15592030 (host).currency => currency>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x155921b0 (host).flag => flag>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x155921f0 (host).url => url>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x15591ee0 (host).countries => countries>"
)>
2014-01-07 14:14:25.411 MyAppName[923:7003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-01-07 14:14:25.415 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:953 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x155a4600> for 'LMCountry' object. Mapping values from object {
    "MyAppName.co.tz" =     {
        countries =         (
            tz
        );
        flag = tz;
        name = Tanzania;
        url = "http://www.MyAppName.co.tz";
    };
} to object <LMCountry: 0x155a60f0> with object mapping (null)
2014-01-07 14:14:25.418 MyAppName[923:7003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:914 Found nested mapping definition to attribute 'host'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.420 MyAppName[923:7003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:917 Found nesting value of 'MyAppName.co.tz' for attribute 'host'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.422 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath '<RK_NESTING_ATTRIBUTE>' to 'host'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.424 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath '<RK_NESTING_ATTRIBUTE>' to 'host'. Value: MyAppName.co.tz
2014-01-07 14:14:25.427 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:605 Skipping attribute mapping for special keyPath '<RK_NESTING_ATTRIBUTE>'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.429 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:617 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'MyAppName.co.tz.name'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.431 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:617 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'MyAppName.co.tz.currency'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.433 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:617 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'MyAppName.co.tz.flag'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.435 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:617 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'MyAppName.co.tz.url'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.437 MyAppName[923:7003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:617 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'MyAppName.co.tz.countries'
2014-01-07 14:14:25.439 MyAppName[923:7003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
```

Comment: Can you post your RestKit mapping code for this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (at least at the time of writing) use `addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute` where the data associated will contain dots because the data is later used as a key and the dots change this into a keypath. This is why the keypath navigation errors occur.

2 potential options:

1. Change the JSON
2. Edit RestKit to not use the data as a keypath (just a key, so `valueForKey:`)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found a couple of pull requests on restkit that will fix this, but for the time being I convinced the api owners to change it.